# If I edit a closed question will it automatically enter the re-open queue?

Tags: support, edits, review, vote-to-reopen

I'm trying to figure out why I saw a question in the re-open queue.  It doesn't appear that the user requested that it be re-opened.  It did have a recent edit from a different user on this site.  If I were to edit a closed question, would it automatically enter the re-open queue?

Comment: Yes, editing a closed question submits it for a reopen, but I *think* it is only when the OP edits it.

Comment: See [Should questions be added to the reopen queue as soon as they're edited by the original author?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157584) for a discussion of the option.

Comment: The case I just saw was *not* an edit by the OP.

Comment: And there were 0 reopen votes on it? Remember that you can vote to reopen someone else's question too. Or perhaps it had been edited by someone else *after* the OP had edited it? What is the link?

Comment: There is a re-open vote on the question now.  I'm not sure if it was there when I found it in the re-open queue.   If so, I didn't see it then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I recall seeing posts in the reopen queue that had no reopen votes, and only were edited by someone other than the OP. I have no links handy as evidence, though. I am very gun-shy on reopen reviews, so I tend to look at them closely.

Comment: The hint box does sometimes say "This post has been edited since it was closed.  Should it be reopened?"

Answer (score 3):

Closed questions are only enqueued in the Reopen queue when the *asker* edits it (within 5 days of its closure).

Comment: Why is that? If I understand the question and improve it, does it not deserve to be reopen visible?