# Nobody in my community has the power to re-open a question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-reopen

I'm part of the LiveCode community. This community discovered Stack Exchange about a year ago and nobody in this community, including myself, has a high enough reputation to re-open questions.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641456/updating-livecode-desktop-app-from-the-web) was put on hold. I have edited the question to make it on-topic. I can do this because being a LiveCode expert I understand exactly what problem the OP is struggling with.

After the question has been edited, it should be submitted for review again, but I, nor anyone else in my community, have the possibility to do this. Currently, Stack Overflow doesn't have a mechanism to ask others to submit a question for review.

Can we add another category to the review lists, where requests to submit questions for review can be posted, or would it be possible to create a different solution for new communities that become active in Stack Overflow?

Comment: You can flag the question for moderator attention, and use the "other" reason to explain why the question should be reopened.

Comment: That looks like a complete rewrite of the question - where did you get the details, including the code? I can see stuff in an _answer_, but there were no comments, not clarification requested from the OP.

Comment: Now, about your question here - suggested edits do go to a queue and will be reviewed. In my opinion, there is way too much change to the question for the edit to be approved (in particular without any additional information from the OP) - your assertion that you are an expert notwithstanding. If it gets approved, it will go to the reopen queue.

Comment: I'm assuming [this is the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2870787) you're referring to?

Comment: @Oded: What are the requirements for edits to go in the reopen queue? I was under the impression [that it only happened if the owner edited the post within 5 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171718/163863).

Comment: @Matt - there is an incoming change that will make _any_ (approved) edits push closed questions into the review queue. Currently live on SO and pushed to the rest of the network next week.

Comment: This question (before and after edit) is far too broad.

Comment: If an on hold question is edited, it goes into a reopen queue.

Comment: related: [Editing Philosophy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194728/editing-philosophy). I for one wouldn't do [edit like you suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2870787), and I find it understandable that it has been rejected

Comment: Please don't undo correct edits @Mark. Users don't have a score, they have reputation. It's that reputation that gives them privileges. That might be the results of scores obtained, but those are certainly not the same. And the tags were added for a reason.

Comment: @Bart, I don't like how the grammar was changed in a bad way.

Comment: I don't see what you're referring to @Mark, but feel free to make corrections. Don't simply undo edits though.

Comment: Mark, I sympathize with your frustration: SO is popular now that it's hard for legitimate authorities of new projects to be heard over all the noise.  But in this case, you should take 24/hours and make sure you are not letting your frustration cloud some legit feedback.  I think the proper thing to do here would have been to ask and answer your own question, maybe even commenting on the original with a link to the new one.

Comment: The problem is that people who have no clue about LiveCode too quickly think that a question is off-topic. If you want a new community to merge with StackOverflow, you should give this community a chance. Clearly, you don't care. All of you.

Comment: @Mark Perhaps you're missing the point. What Oded explained to you is that a feature has been rolled out which will, after appropriate accepted edits, push such questions in the reopen queue. This means it will be brought to the attention of the wider community. That should effectively achieve what you're asking for.

Comment: "Nobody in my community has the power to re-open a question" ....And?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue)

Answer (score 25):

We already have the mechanisms for this, and they work.

If a user doesn't have enough reputation to make a direct edit to a post, they can suggest an edit, as you have done.

Other users will review it. If it is approved, [it will go into the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/), where, if the question now has enough merit it will get reopened.

---

Now, in this particular case, when it comes to this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2870787) by yourself, this is a *radical* change to the post. It is a complete rewrite and contains code examples that the original doesn't have.

Your assertion in the edit summary that you are an expert and know about the technology is not relevant. Such a change should be done only after input from the OP; that input doesn't exist (no comments on the question or the existing answer), so it is unclear where you got them from or that these actually reflect the situation that the OP is in.

I can see now that the suggested edit was rejected, as it should have.

Comment: I will not accept your answer, because you mainly explain why my edit should be rejected, rather than telling me how the process works. After a post is edited, nothing indicates that it is submitted for review again.
Whether or not my edit should be accepted is not the subject of the debate here.

Comment: Possibly people need to be informed better of what happens after an edit to a closed post is approved, but the process itself is good

Comment: @Oded, Are you sure that edits by a third party cause the question to enter the reopen queue? [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186728/209087) in another question seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @user000001 - Yes. This is a very _recent_ change and is live only on a few sites (including SO). It will be rolled out everywhere next week.

Comment: @Oded That's awesome. Thanks for adding that feature.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - thank m0sa for implementing.

Comment: @Mark *"After a post is edited, nothing indicates that it is submitted for review again."* I'm not sure what you mean. This answer right here indicates that a post is submitted for review once edited. See the second and third paragraphs of the answer.