# Lots of questions in the reopen queue

Tags: support, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I've noticed in the last couple of days that there have been a few occasions when there's been a sudden surge of questions in the SO "Reopen" review queue.

Normally there's either no questions at all to reopen or at most three or four, and that's still the case, except that for the last couple of days I've gone to the review page and seen about fifty-odd questions in the queue, where just moments before there had been none.

I've gone through the reviews and the questions themselves seem reasonably legitimate (including the occasional audit), so I'm not questioning that... it just seems odd that there would be so many more than usual all of a sudden, and that they'd all appear at once.

Anyone got any insights, or should I just chalk this down as "one of those things"?

Comment: The sudden influx may be due to [a recent, unannounced change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196026/nobody-in-my-community-has-the-power-to-re-open-a-question/196028#196028): now all edits to a closed question push a question into the reopen queue, not just edits by the asker.

Comment: @Gilles Pretty sure that's what's going on, based on my experience using the queue that's accounting for a significant percentage of the items.

Comment: fair enough. I'll accept that as plausible. But any reason why they'd all suddenly appear in the queue at once?

Comment: @Spudley since the feature hasn't been announced, I think we'll have to let a SE employee answer why they just appear, but best guess is there is a script that adds them to the queue, and it only runs every few minutes.

Comment: People go on editing binges, some that include a lot of closed questions, a lot more often then people go on reopen-binges.  A lot of the items are people going around retagging, or doing other serial edits.

Comment: yeah, fair enough I guess. (that said, @Servy, I'm really not convinced that a retag should be sufficient to trigger it into the reopen queue!)

Comment: @Servy Only edits made during the first 5 days push a question into the reopen queue. (That's the one thing that changes between on-hold and closed.) Thus clean-up mass edits that affect a long-quiescent closed question won't make it more likely that the question is reopened (someone could cast the first vote outside the queue, obviously).

Comment: @Spudley I agree, but having recently reviewed a whole string of retagged questions by a single user, I can assure you it currently is doing exactly that.

Comment: @Gilles Still, there are a lot of mass-edits by single users that hit enough recently closed questions.  The reviews that I've done in the past few days have resulted in plenty of observational evidence of that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem which caused this question, that all questions edited after closing were added to the reopen queue, no longer exists. The system no longer does so (it only does so if the editor checks a box, and only a small percentage of edits after closure have the box checked). The answer here is also outdated as a result of this change, and a new answer wouldn't answer this question (asking why there are lots of questions, which there no longer are).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

On September 6th, 2013, the automatic triggers for putting questions into the reopen queue changed. They were tweaked repeatedly over the years and, as of December 20th, 2019, a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...

1. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by the author. Or,
2. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it. Or,
3. ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month.

Note: for #2 (3rd-party edits), any flag raised by the editor *other than* "moderator intervention" disqualifies the edit from consideration, even when the flag comes after the edit, is declined, or is retracted by the flagger. Flag types *include* close and reopen votes, which are represented as flags internally. [There are some unintended consequences to how this is handled](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/why-was-this-reopen-review-item-invalidated/3351#3351).

As always, a reopen vote will add a question to the reopen queue *if* it isn't already in the queue. However, a reopen vote by the same user whose edit pushed the question into the reopen queue will result in the question being *removed* from the reopen queue if:

- there are no other reopen votes more than (roughly) 15 minutes old, *and*
- the reopen vote was cast *after* the voter's edit had already added the question to the queue

### Background

Previously, if the author edited a closed post within 5 days of it being closed, [that would trigger it to be added to the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157584/should-questions-be-added-to-the-reopen-queue-as-soon-as-theyre-edited-by-the-o). This was a great way to get additional views for questions that might've been improved enough to be re-opened, but it didn't do much for [questions that 3rd-parties *without* the ability to vote for reopen think should be re-opened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/can-we-have-the-ability-to-flag-for-reopening/186728#186728).

So the heuristics mentioned above are effectively a way of avoiding yet another flag and thus requiring two actions to enqueue a question: they are things that *might* indicate a closed question that could use some additional review - or if nothing else, at least a question that *someone* still cares about.

Comment: heh, so my guesstimate of "fifty-odd" was spot on... who'd have thought it?  :-)

Comment: Don't know whether the "closed in the past year" rule works as expected. We just got http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/can-i-upgrade-directly-from-mac-os-x-10-5-leopard-to-10-7-lion in the Reopen queue (and several more of about the same age). Not too big of a problem right now at least...

Comment: That one was added due to the number of views, @patrix.

Comment: Fair point, maybe "duplicates" shouldn't score so high in general then bacause the topic itself is actively covered by another question already so the risk of them remaining buried is lower (compared to questions closed for other reasons)

Comment: That's a fair point @patrix (although I have seen some incorrectly-closed duplicates crop up). Feature-request...

Comment: Maybe you guys could remove the Revision tab on these when there's no actual revision... A bit misleading. It confused me a *lot* at first. *"Why are there so many revision-less revised questions?"*

Comment: Could this be taught to ignore  retags, whitespace edits, capitalization edits, and removal of salutation lines?

Comment: It already ignores retags, @Manishearth - "(body edits only)". Trying to differentiate between a significant and an insignificant body edit is beyond the capability of the system.

Comment: @Shog9 http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/22818

Comment: Heh... Without checking, I'm gonna wager it was actually Community's edit that triggered the review there. Since these don't happen anymore, this should be a temporary problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks then :)

Comment: @Shog9 Over on SA, we only have about 13 10k users, and not all of those are active.  Suggest smaller sites get tuned to no more than say 5 auto-reevalutes per day to reduce the burden.  Also, they don't seem to be worth reopening almost ever, judging by the 20 from yesterday over on SA.  Maybe the criteria can be tuned.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Or maybe a max queue size? If we're getting through them (which we will start doing, if only because I will be mod-hammering at least some) no harm in it giving us more to do.

Comment: Also, if the reason is an active re-edit by OP, that is the strongest evidence in my opinion that a re-evaluation is warranted; having that information highlighted on the review page would be very nice.  Or an active reopen vote, of course.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: we can (and probably will) raise the bar for these, but let's give it a few days to flush out the cruft first - a lot of the crap flowing through right now is due to the Community editor past that Manis noted above.

Comment: FWIW, the Community-edits thing was fixed a little while ago, and the current rules for "popularity" are also considerably more strict. We'll continue to watch and tweak these as time goes on.

Comment: Does flag also include a reopen vote?

Comment: Yes, @ShafikYaghmour - but a reopen vote will itself add the post to the queue.

Comment: Makes sense, it was not clear from your description. I had edited a question to get into better shape that I had voted to reopen hours before and was wondering why it did not end up back in the queue.

Comment: Yeah, generally, you'll want to edit *before* you vote if possible, @Shafik - this gives reviewers a better question to consider.

Comment: You are correct, I should know that by now. I was relying on being able to edit later on if my comment was not sufficient but now I know my understanding was incorrect.

Comment: Have the criteria for "Sufficiently popular" stabilized by now? Do they apply network-wide?

Comment: No, they're probably too high @127 - but we've been tweaking a bunch of other stuff. And yes, they apply network-wide.

Comment: Is the second of these (third-party edit *so long as* the editor didn't vote to close) still correct?  As a moderator I will sometimes close a question immediately if I don't have time to fix it right then, and then come back some hours later to edit the question.  I'd been assuming all along that my edits would send the question to the reopen queue.  If not, how should moderators handle that case?

Comment: Moderators should directly reopen questions they fix, @Monica. We don't vote to give people powerful tools so they can mess around creating work for other people.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you clarify that last line? In particular, if a question is (1) edited, (2) receives three Leave Closed votes, and then (3) gets an independent reopen vote, does that put it back on the queue?

Comment: Yes, @E.P. - under normal circumstances, it would be reviewed twice in that scenario.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. So any reopen vote will pop it on the queue regardless of how many times it's been in it? It might be worth making the language a bit sharper to make that clearer.

Comment: That's not quite true either, @E.P. - an accurate description would be, "a new reopen vote will create a review task *if there are no active reopen votes or review tasks for the post*".

Comment: Oh, OK, I see it.

Comment: [My answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410755/3023052) has some new details on how the problem with invalidated edits/reopen votes will be fixed in an upcoming release.