# Reopen review queue showing wrong reason for reopening

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

Have a look at [this reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2878651). It was showing *"This question was edited after it was closed"* as a reason to reopen. But [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238603/1369235) was **not** edited after it was closed.

The last edit was on `Oct 26 '08 at 21:15`.

> [image]

And it was closed on `Nov 28 '11 at 22:44`

[image]

Also there is no revision in the review page:

> [image]

Actually it was in the queue because someone voted to reopen. I think this happens due to [this new feature.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/187824)

See some examples from Meta review queue:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17897
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17887
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17877