# Is there a delay between edit and question appearing in Reopen Votes review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

According to [this question & answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209143/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-question-to-appear-in-the-reopen-queue), a question should appear in reopen queue less than an hour after an edit. However, I noticed that most of the edited questions in my review queue have last edit a few days back. I'm talking about the questions with reason "This question was edited after it was closed." Why haven't these questions appear in my review queue earlier? Are they intentionally delayed or it is a bug (i.e., they are there because of reopen vote rather than edit) or something else I don't understand?

I.e., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393677/understanding-android-application-execution) just appeared in my queue, while it has been edited a few days back.

Comment: FWIW there is a reason why it just bumped back into the Reopen Votes queue (it's already been in there before), but I'm on my phone and don't feel like explaining it.

Comment: @animuson: presumably because someone manually voted to reopen it?

Comment: @Martijn It's a tad more complicated than that, but yes.

Comment: I would explain it, but I don't feel like depriving @animuson of the opportunity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so to understand how this question ended up in the Reopen Votes queue *again*, you need a bit of a timeline of events that a normal user would not really have access to see (anonymized, of course):

```
Time               Event
---------------------------------------
Jan 28 at 5:51     Post Closed
Jan 28 at 9:09     Post Edited
Jan 28 at 9:26     Post Enters Reopen Queue
Jan 28 at 9:27     Reopen Vote #1 (through Queue)
Jan 28 at 9:29     Reopen Review Completes (Left Closed)

Jan 28 at 10:56    Reopen Vote #2

Feb 2 at 03:00     Expire Reopen Vote #1
Feb 2 at 03:03     Post Enters Reopen Queue
Feb 2 at 03:08     Reopen Review Completes (Left Closed)
```

Now, as you can see, the question received two reopen votes. One occurred during the review process, and one occurred after the review process had already completed. Understanding the process of expiring reopen votes, it takes 4 days from the last reopen vote for the oldest vote to expire. So, on February 2nd when the 3am process ran, it expired that first reopen vote, and left the system with a dilemma:

It now has a *new* reopen vote that occurred on the question *outside* of the review item's window. That means it needs to be bumped into the Reopen Votes queue again so that the question can be reviewed (again). It just had to wait for that other reopen vote to expire before it could do that (if it were to keep receiving reopen votes at a rate of at least 1 in fewer than 4 days, it would get reopened without need for review). If the second reopen vote had occurred *inside* the review queue as part of a review, a second review would not have been necessary; it wouldn't bump back in for another reopen vote until after all those votes that occurred inside that review had expired.

So this question *actually* entered the Reopen Votes queue because of another reopen vote, and it was actually the second time it had been in review (the first time was for an edit).

**Also note:** This is unverified, but I remember reading somewhere that an edit can only bump a question into the Reopen Votes queue *once*. Further edits would not continue bumping it into review. I could not find a source for that, though.

**Possibly related:** [Reopen review queue showing wrong reason for reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196156/reopen-review-queue-showing-wrong-reason-for-reopening?rq=1)

@Devs Feel free to fix anything that looks like I'm just making things up.

Comment: So, then it seems like a bug since it is in a queue not because of an edit.

Comment: Yes, that's why I linked that question at the end there.