# Can multiple edits send an [on-hold] question to Reopen queue more than once?

Tags: support, review, edits, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

I'd like to have this [remark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218420/)  by animuson confirmed or refuted:

> This is unverified, but I remember reading somewhere that an edit can only bump a question into the Reopen Votes queue once. Further edits would not continue bumping it into review. I could not find a source for that, though.

I could not find a source, either. There is an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/) of how edits send questions into Reopen queue, but it does not address this point.

My reason for asking: I often see  questions with minor formatting edits (made by someone other than OP) in the Reopen queue. The reviewers decide to *Leave Closed*, since the reason for closure still applies. Suppose that  OP edits the question later; will the edit send it to be reviewed again? If not, this means that minor  edits to an on-hold question *reduce* the chance of the question being reopened.

Comment: Shog9's answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572 confirms the remark. The last sentence I quote: "A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing. It will be enqueued once per reopen vote as long as there are no outstanding reopen votes that've already triggered a review."

Comment: Thanks; I did not think to search meta.SO for this.

Comment: Don't thank me. Thank Google. `:-)`

Comment: This statement in the proposed duplicate indicates both "yes", and that the decision may be revisited: > "Multiple opportunities to send question for review

We’ll be launching this feature without any limits – users will be able to submit multiple edits on individual posts. We’ll take a look at the data in a few weeks to see if any abuse of the feature has occurred and take mitigation steps as needed.". Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/282094

Answer (score 11):

[Shog9 answered this question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/):

> A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing. It will be enqueued once per reopen vote *as long as* there are no outstanding reopen votes that've already triggered a review.

Comment: interesting that this isn't the case for close queue; when prior votes expire, question can re-enter it: [Same question goes through close review queue twice, is that good or bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195080/165773)

Comment: But this is the same for reopen *votes*, as the second sentence says. Only *edit-induced reviews*  are limited to "once per closure".

Comment: ah I see! that makes more sense now, thanks