# Improving a 'What is the best" kind of question

Tags: discussion

Now and then I find myself reading a question that starts like

- what is the best way to do X on Y?
  or
- which is the best X on Y?

Most of these questions are marked as "not constructive". Nevertheless, quite a number of them are useful. A solution may be to require the author to change the question to a technical one, like

- How can X be done on Y? 
  or
- Are there X that one can apply on Y?

instead of closing a question for not being constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can see your way to rewording such a question without changing its intent, then go right ahead and do so!

Even if the question has already been closed by the time you make your edit, it can still be reopened. We even [made changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078) recently to increase the visibility for such edited questions.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, this is basically what happens - note that the questions **are not closed**, but **put on hold** if they do have serious problems.

The problem will also be displayed as clearly as possible to let the user understand why his question does not fit the site's standards. He is then encouraged to improve the question; if he does it will automatically end up in the reopen review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Questions are put "On Hold" before being closed to allow users to make changes to improve their question to fit the SO format.