# Bug with the new reopen review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

I know that there was a change to [how questions are automatically added to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/186843)

But while reviewing today on [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) I noticed that many questions were also in the queue yesterday. I think that is a bug.

> [image: screenshot today]

When you look at one of the questions, you will see that the last activity was weeks ago, but the question appeared in the review queue yesterday and today.

I understand that the change also pulls in older questions that should be reviewed, but I expect this to happen only once. Why should we review the same questions when nothing has changed?

> [image: screenshot yesterday]

Comment: Why is that a bug? Are those questions not closed, or not edited?

Comment: when you look at one of the questions, you will see that the last activity was weeks ago, but the question appeared in the review queue yesterday and today

Comment: The change also pulls in older questions that should be reviewed.

Comment: yeah, but only once. Why should we review the same questions when nothing has changed?

Comment: Right, so older questions you reviewed yesterday reappeared today. That'd be a bug.

Comment: There's something else funny going on... on ServerFault, I just saw the count of items to review drop by 9 while the number of reviews went up by 3.  (I was hitting refresh and saw one guy's count go up, and the items to review dropped.)  A few minutes later, the count of items to review dropped from 36 to 20, but the count of reviews only went up by 2.

Comment: This same thing is appearing on DBA.SE and here on Meta. Items I reviewed yesterday are appearing today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone reported [this one in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11155480#11155480) and it was fixed immediately. The review queues should be running as expected since the 2013.9.10.* revision.

Just in case you're wondering, the reason wasn't i18n this time.