# Review message is wrong in the case of popular posts in the Reopen Queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

I got this review in the Reopen Queue.

> [image]

Clicking on <kbd>Revision</kbd> I got:

> [image]

<s>Why are there *no changes to diplay* if the question is in the queue because of being *edited*?</s>

If this question is in the queue [because of being popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/200868) (reason 3, thanks @George) and not because of being *edited*, then the review message/prompt should say *that*.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/161467 My interpretation of reason number 3 is that it doesn't necessarily need to have been edited. I guess in that case the tab should be hidden.

Comment: As an aside, with this new "rule" - I've noticed that a lot of the *same questions* that were in the Reopen Votes queue yesterday (here on Meta) are back in the queue *again* today. What gives? Are we going to keep reviewing the same questions over and over?

Comment: @animuson See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196448/223030, which seems to be the canonical bug report for that.