# New reopen queue offers the same questions the next day

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday a change to the reopen review queue, in which [old questions meeting certain criteria are added to the queue daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196074/189912), went live on Server Fault.

Yesterday I went through about three dozen of them, since I hadn't seen the meta post about the change and having 83 posts suddenly appear in the reopen queue appeared to be some kind of fluke.

Today I started going through them and thought some of them looked awfully familiar. When I looked at the [review history](https://serverfault.com/review/reopen/history), I see that half or more of the questions I'm seeing today are the same as those I saw yesterday!

Though I was already suspicious when 83 posts got added to the queue again today...

Why do the same questions keep reappearing?

Comment: So will either of the duplicate questions get any sort of answer or comment about what's wrong?