# How to get a question to reopen review queue?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

There is a question: [How to list open ports in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737305/how-to-list-open-ports-in-ios)

Originally, it wasn't well written. It wasn't obvious that it has anything to do with programming. Also, it was quite short. And as happens to many other short, not well written questions - it was closed.

Now, me (I am not OP) and another person (also not OP) are trying to open it, because it's quite interesting question (in quite narrow jailbreak development area). So, we both voted to reopen it and we both upvoted it and we edited it to become more legit SO question.

Now, my question is. What can I do additionally to get this question to reopen review queue?

Comment: Probably nothing. It should already _be_ in the reopen queue.

Comment: It's been reopened now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the meta effect, the question has already been reopened because it got eyes here. **However**, casting a single reopen vote would be enough to get the post into the reopen queue (you wouldn't be able to see it there if you already casted a vote).

Also, [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/215468) cause questions that undergo any body edits to be put into the reopen queue automatically.

> So rather than implementing some new boring impotent flag for this purpose, we decided to take other criteria into account, things that might indicate a closed question that could use some additional review. Currently, this means that **a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue** when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to
>     close it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still
>     tweaking the exact thresholds for these.
>
> As always, a reopen vote will add a question to the reopen queue *if*
>   it isn't already in the queue.
>
> *By Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/215468)*

Comment: Ah... I didn't know about inability to see a question in this queue if you voted. So, I voted first and went to check whether it's in reopen queue now.

Answer (score 2):

The linked question was closed again by five community members, under the *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"* close reason, which seems incorrect, so I reopened it (again).

Note that the *"tool, library or favorite off-site resource"* close reason is intended for product recommendation and shopping questions, not questions asking for code or algorithms.  If you want to close the question under a different theory, perhaps *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved,"* then please, feel free to do so.