# Many reopen votes available in the review queue

Tags: discussion, support, review

I have just noticed that we have had 63 reopen votes in the review queue all of a sudden. I was doing reviews, it was zero when it got bumped all. I am wondering why this may have happened. See the screenshot below.

[image]

I have [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue) thread where the root cause was a change in the workflow, so I wonder if there is similar here again, or it is because of something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why?  Hats!  Edits will cause reopens for closed questions.  There is a hat for 'edit 10 posts', and another 'edit 90 days old post' and another 'edit a cw post'.  Likewise the 'Reanimated' for reopening a question.  It might also be related to the decline in close votes (maybe people are doing reviews?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was an error in the automated processes which did a lot of things, including expiring close votes, deleting questions, and some other tasks. This was just fixed yesterday, and is why the Close Votes queue has also dropped almost 6,000 questions since then.

03:00 UTC just passed again, and the automated processes have had another chance to run. If you were around at 03:00 UTC yesterday, there was also a dramatic spike in the Reopen Votes queue then.

Comment: boooooooooooring. I liked the hat answer

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I have not realized the drop in the close votes, but you are absolutely right. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is hats. Blame the winter bash. People now are engaging in lots of activities that they would not so they can get their hats. I am one of those people. The hats now control my life. I live for hats. I spend every second of my day researching those secret hats, trying to figure out how I can get them. I found out that to get the With Great Power... badge, you must either be a mod, or pay the dev team $1337.

Hail HAtwood, lord of hats!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I forgot to mention in my question that it is on stackoverflow rather than meta. Do hats relate to that, too?

Comment: @LaszloPapp [hats](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) are *everywhere*.

Comment: Well SO is exponentially bigger than MSO, so that may have something to do with it

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: yeah, animuson wrote that in his answer, thanks.