# Massive spike in first posts?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review, new-users

I was just taking a look at the reviews, and I saw that the amount of first posts jumped by over 400. It usually hovers around 0. Take a look

[image]

Also, most of the things I'm reviewing in that are not first posts at all, they're from people with a good amount of rep

Comment: Sorry I couldn't add a freehand circle. Editors, feel free to add them

Comment: Related to: [Many reopen votes available in the review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212280/many-reopen-votes-available-in-the-review-queue)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our daily task has been a bit <strike>constipated</strike> backed up and tonight's run removed about 13,000 [old, abandoned, closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Of those 13K, about 400 were the previous "first posts" by their owners - now that they were deleted, the next post by each owner became eligible to be in the queue.  And our queue system obliged, creating the bump.

One could argue this is incorrect behavior, but my take is it allows more eyes on content that probably does need reviewing (the owners' previous first posts were just auto-deleted!).

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the Christmas hats campaign the Stack Exchange network is running right now. See here: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/. Users are given an incentive to participate in other parts of the network in order to earn gifts.

This is another go at gamification, albeit a seasonal version and from the new posts I would say that it is working! :)

Comment: I don't think so, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212280/many-reopen-votes-available-in-the-review-queue/212283#212283, and take a look at my answer and the accepted answer

Comment: Ah, this question looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe, but different queue

Comment: Nope. At least not intentionally. We're not boosting review queues just for the purpose of hats.