# Allow me to flag to close even if I already used my close vote

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, reopened-questions

When a question I voted to close gets reopened, I cannot vote to close it again, because everybody [can vote to close a given question successfully only once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/255554). I understand this as it avoids close wars and similar abuse.

However, in this situation, I can not even **flag** to close. I can only flag as *spam/offensive* or flag for moderator attention. While moderators can deal with this, [they can only do so with a unilateral vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/255554) but have no option to just send it to the close queue. Also, moderators need not necessarily be bothered with this.

In the following situations, flagging such a question would make sense in my opinion:

- I vote to close a question as *unclear.* It gets clarified and reopened, but through the clarification I can see that it’s a duplicate.
- A reopened question is rendered closeworthy by a change in site policy.
- A user nominates a question again and again for reopening until they succeed by chance. This happened with [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22400/2594) ([first](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/10345), [second](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/10745) and [third](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/11000) attempt). While this particular question should arguably have been discussed on Meta before another attempt for closure (and another solution was found anyway), this situation is also prone to abuse by particularly stubborn users.

Comment: If you're the only user on the site who thinks the question should be closed... I think you should let it be. Otherwise, bring it to the attention of others who are able to flag or vote to close.

Comment: *bring it to the attention of others who are able to flag or vote to close* – Which is exactly what flagging to close does.

Comment: "everybody can only once vote to close a given question" ... I think they allow you to vote again if your previous vote expired (the question remained undecided for a long time and votes were cleared).

Comment: @muru: Only if your previous vote to close was unsuccessful and did not lead to closure. I am pretty certain about the facts here, as I experienced them today.

Comment: @muru No, that's not the case.  It doesn't matter if the question was reopened or the vote aged out; in either case you can't vote again.

Comment: @Servy: If the vote aged out unsuccessfully, you can vote again. Go to [your close history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186381/servy?tab=votes&sort=closure) and search for some old question that you voted to close and that was never closed. You should be able to vote to close it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft No, you can't.  I can tell you from experience that you cannot.

Comment: @Servy: How old is that experience? I just did what I described and could vote to close the question. See also [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/255554).

Answer (score 3):

Having only a single close or reopen vote will effectively prevent abuse. It will also keep questions from re-appearing in the review queue again and again after there happened to be community dispute on the close or reopen reasons.

On a small site, only few users may be active in the review queues. It then can indeed happen that some of those few users occasionally lose their ability to vote again, thus making the review queue less effective.

But I believe that **this is extremely rare**. In such extraordinary cases, the way to go is to ask a moderator to step in by raising a *moderator attention* flag, ping them in chat, or start a Meta discussion if it was a recurring issue.

Comment: *Having only a single close or reopen vote … will also keep questions from re-appearing in the review queue again and again* – Actually, since [this change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/255554), it only does if the close vote was effective. For example, if I am eager to reopen a question, I can bring it to the reopen queue every 14 days until I succeed (which was more or less was what eventually lead to this question). So, while I see your point on keeping questions from reappearing, this is something that only works in this case, which is admittedly rare.

Comment: Actually the reopen queue can immediately be triggered by an edit, no need to wait for 14 days.

Comment: Nope, it doesn’t. [This only works for the first five days.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/255554)