# Question put on hold

Tags: support, on-hold

My original question was put on hold with a message saying "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question."

I have edited my question to be very specific. Why is it still on hold?

Here is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514290/how-can-i-use-php-with-the-paypal-api-to-retrieve-transaction-data-for-an-accoun

Comment: Editing it doesn't mean it will automatically reopened. Every edit is reviewed by humans. It takes time to review such things. And if the edit doesn't seem useful, it will never be reopened. (Also, this is Meta Stack Exchange, you should have posted on Meta Stack Overflow, where the Stack Overflow site is discussed).

Comment: see [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773) "a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is..." etc

Comment: And just for some further help, as you are a new user here, you are getting downvoted here (likely) because "doesn't show any research effort". A search would likely have answered your question, here or on meta.stackoverflow.com. Also, reading about how the site works in the help center(s) is a valuable thing to do as a new user. There are lots of things here on Stack Exchange which are not like other sites :)

Comment: Irony: Question put on hold [on hold]

Answer (score 6):

This should be posted in the Stack Overflow Meta, not here.

But I'll answer anyway: once your question has been edited it is then placed in a review queue, where helpful people with sufficient reputation can vote whether to reopen it. If the question gets five reopen votes then the post notice is removed and the question is reopened. But there is no guarantee, it might still remain closed - I seldom vote to reopen when I do reviews in that queue. But if you've added enough to make it answerable then you might make it.

Comment: at MSO, this question would be closed as duplicate of [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/839601)

Answer (score 4):

Once a closed question is edited in the way you describe, it is placed on the re-open queue.

The question will be re-opened when (if) it obtains enough votes to be re-opened.

Be patient.