# Is it acceptable to edit unsalvageable closed questions during tag cleanups?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, closed-questions

At Super User, there is [a huge ongoing campaign](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/380318) to destroy numerous bad tags. Boatloads of the questions with those tags are closed and not repairable. Sadly, they mostly have (mediocre) answers, and thus won't be automatically demolished by Community.

If we don't completely remove the tags, people will just keep using them, despite the obvious "Do not use this tag!" text in the excerpt. (Sigh.) I know editing terrible closed questions is lame because it puts them in the Reopen Votes queue and shoves them onto the front page, but these tags need to go. What should we do?

Comment: FWIW edits push questions to reopen queue only within 5 days of closure [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773)

Comment: Can't the mods or CMs kill a tag without editing every single question?

Comment: The mods could also kill the questions without even editing the tags, but then that's probably a lot of mod-specific work.