# Should grammar edits of closed questions be approved?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review, suggested-edits, closed-questions

If a question is closed or put on hold, usually nobody bothers to fix spelling mistakes in it. But if a new user does it, should the edit be approved? It does technically edit the post, although not in a way that could possibly lead to it getting reopened.

Basically the question comes down to "is that an appropriate way to gain reputation"? Do we trust users more because they can find poorly spelled questions and correct them? On the other hand, editing questions is often pointed out as a good way to get comment privileges and closed question are an obvious source for edit-worthy looking posts.

Comment: Wow, I searched for "edit closed question" and it gave me a lot of results, but not the "editing of answers to closed questions" one.

Comment: @Notts90: don't you think it's a trifle cheeky to dupe-link an author back to their own question covering the other side of the case?

Comment: @Fabian: Note that the answer you've accepted is currently sitting at +4/-3 and does not represent any particularly compelling consensus, so you may want to reconsider leaving the signal of agreement there.

Comment: +4/-4 now, @NathanTuggy.

Comment: Actually, I just forgot that I had asked that before (and apparently didn't find it by searching). Yes, it is a duplicate and the answer there is more precise (and has a better score).

Comment: What? Accepting it as duplicate of one question instead marked it as duplicate of three other questions? Why? Here's the link that I intended to accept: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303476/edits-on-closed-posts

Comment: The third one also answers this question, but differently.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I never looked at the author. I judged the questions on their own merits as I don't see how the author makes a difference to if its a dupe or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any valid edit should be approved without consideration of the status of the question or reputation gain.  That is, that the question is closed should not be a basis for rejecting the edit.

Any real contribution to and participation in the community should enhance trust.  It might be incidental, but really how much reputation can users generate by patrolling as grammar cops?  A really popular question can generate serious reputation, while an approved edit can net only 2.  There is also a cap on total reputation gained this way (1000).  Perhaps this consideration was instrumental in determining these restrictions.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the once-in-a-question's-lifetime chance at the Reopen Queue should be blown off quite so easily, with literally *no* consideration whatsoever.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's a great point, but entirely beside the point of this question.

Comment: Really? "It does technically edit the post, although not in a way that could possibly lead to it getting reopened." Given this, it seems perfectly relevant. And the fact that you explicitly stated that the closed state should not be considered at all means that you're taking a stand on this, whether or not you intended to. If your advice has unfortunate side effects, I'm going to point them out, whether or not the question asked "Oh, by the way, make sure this extremely particular side effect doesn't crop up in your answers." Same as downvoting an answer on SO because it leads to bad security.

Comment: It is relevant, but still beside the point.  I stated that reputation gain should not be considered, and that the closed state should not be basis for rejecting it.  This consideration mutates the question from "is this a legitimate way to gain reputation" to "should I reject an edit because it could be better?"  I may or may not take such a stand on that question, but this isn't that question.  Your comment makes a great point, but it is not the point of the question, and should not influence the answer.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know about the once only chance (look at my rep, I just earned the right to downvote), and I am not against that being a basis for rejecting the edit.  I might have added that as a frame challenge component of the question if I had, but it would not be a direct answer since it is only related to the topic of the question, and not the actual question itself.