# Let users editing a question know if editing it would add it to the reopen queue

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

This is *sort of* similar to [Let reviewers know if a suggested edit will push the question into the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307590/let-reviewers-know-if-a-suggested-edit-will-push-the-question-into-the-reopen-qu), which was positively received, but was declined for technical reasons.

I propose that users who are editing a post that was closed within the last five days be shown a notice on top of the edit form indicating that the post will be added to the reopen queue if edited, and that if one does not plan on editing the post into a state where it can be reopened, one should wait until five days after closure to make the edit.

Closed questions are only added to the review queue once per closure by editing, and if a user comes by and makes a minor (yet benign) edit, the diff that reopen reviewers see is just that of the minor edit, and as such they dismiss the task as "Leave Closed", which prevents it from being added to the queue again by another edit. This deprives the post author (and others interested in seeing the question reopened) of their chance to get the post reopened by editing.

While some of these edits may be performed by users using (semi-)automated tools who would thus not see or overlook the warning, this will be a big help because 99%+ of users make edits solely manually and would thus see and possibly respond to such a notice.

To help make this request more technically feasible, I propose that it instead only be loaded with the edit form, and that it should only be shown to users who can make binding edits. (Suggested edits occur at the time of approval, and the request to let the reviewers know has already been declined.)

Here's an example of what I'm expecting:

> #### This question was recently [closed/marked as duplicate].
>
> This question will be added to a queue for possible reopening if you make this edit. If you are not planning to edit this post into a state where it can be reopened, please wait until [date and time after 70 days] to make your edit.
>
> If you are only making edits to the question's tags, please ignore this notice.

Comment: If you're going to detect this scenario at all, I think it makes more sense to let the editor optionally uncheck a box to stop their edit from pushing the question into the reopen queue, rather than encourage them not to edit at all. We shouldn't be discouraging people from tidying up things they see that are wrong and that they're inclined to fix.

Comment: @MarkAmery Make that an answer, I like that idea.

Comment: I also like the idea of an option not to push an edited question into the Reopen review queue, but note that a checkbox has already been proposed and status-declined: [Give 2k users a 'don't put this in the reopen queue' checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183233/410681)

Comment: @MarkAmery [Filed a reconsideration request asking for that ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326978/add-a-checkbox-to-indicate-whether-a-third-party-edit-makes-the-question-reopena).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has not been implemented the way you suggested, but I think the [final release of the Review Queues Workflows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) has adequately addressed the underlying problem. Users now have to actively indicate that their edit resolves the close reason:

[image]

Comment: Should it be marked with status-completed or status-declined then (or both?)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: [status-completed] makes sense to me, as the implemented method is still "let[ting] users editing a question know if editing it would add it to the reopen queue" by way of letting the editor choose whether the edit does so.