# Trivial edits of recently closed questions - inform editor of consequences?

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

Having yet again rejected a small edit<sup>[1]</sup> on a recently closed question because it will kill the OP's chances of it reaching a correct review to reopen, I wondered if it would be possible to inform editors if they attempt this.

[Editing of recently closed questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13646/editing-of-recently-closed-questions) for relevant background to this.

Of course, in an ideal world, the more experienced reviewers will always reject the edits - but the editor will presumable never find out **why**.
It's been a while since I was new enough to see what notification you might get on a review, whether successful, or otherwise, but as I recall it's nothing more than 2 points popping up in your score dock… or not, by which time you've probably forgotten.

Perhaps for all editors, not just new users, who attempt an edit on a closed post within 5 days of its closure?
Some notification along the lines of

> "Any edit to a closed post will promote it to the Reopen Review queue; thus depriving the original author of the chance to have any relevant informational edit to their question reviewed for reopening.
> Closed, edited posts only have one chance to be reviewed for reopening."

*My wording could probably be improved*

<sup>[1]</sup> An otherwise perfectly acceptable edit, which would have raised the question back to the top of the Active list, but caused no other issues.

There is this, related Meta - [Set a rep threshold for editing closed questions?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11854/set-a-rep-threshold-for-editing-closed-questions) suggesting a different approach; one I'm not keen on, especially as low rep doesn't always signify new user to Stack Exchange, maybe just a stack in which a more generally experienced user has a relatively small interest.

Comment: Just a quick note with the migration - while this was asked on Super User meta, I feel that it could potentially be a broader quality of life improvement for new users

Comment: Already requested: [Let users editing a question know if editing it would add it to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313932/let-users-editing-a-question-know-if-editing-it-would-add-it-to-the-reopen-queue) (cc @JourneymanGeek)

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog - I hadn't checked on here for dupes, of course, as I originally posted on SU Meta. I'd consider it 'nearly but not quite' a dupe, just because though the end result is similar the suggested route to it is slightly different. It may also be useful to gather further opinion/staff consideration. (Of course, I'm happy whichever way the community decides as to its dupe potential)(.

Comment: Alternatively I suggest that only edits by the original author should send a question to the reopen queue, not edits by other users.

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's how it *used* to work back when the whole "edit-to-reopen" feature was introduced, but it was later expanded to edits from everyone because <3k users who weren't the author of a post had no way to push questions into the reopen queue.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Based on my experience when I had <3k, I still think the way you say it worked previously was better, since when I had <3k I never even thought of editing someone else's question in order to get it reopened. When I had <3k and wanted someone else's question to be reopened, I would either just leave it alone or flag for moderator attention, depending on how strongly I felt about each specific case. I do think though that a reopen flag for <3k users would be useful, in the same way as there are close flags.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I believe there was discussion around creating a "recommend reopen" flag to complement recommend closure flags, but it was decided not to because they feared that people will just click it to contest questions without giving any real reason to reopen, unlike with close flags where one has to specify a reason for closing. So they decided to implement an easy technical solution, to allow <3k users to queue questions for reopening with less perceived risk of questions simply ending up there without any clear arguments as to why they should be reopened.

Comment: I did make another feature request, a reconsideration request for a previously declined feature request to add a checkbox for users to indicate whether the question should be added to the queue or not, but for several reasons including one part of it weakening my argument and it meeting the "wrong crowd", it ended up heavily downvoted. I'd like to see someone else make another clearer case for doing that, based on that first declined request and my later downvoted reconsideration request.