# Keeping good questions out of the Phantom Zone

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I've encountered a situation several times recently where the timing of actions on a question sent a good question to the Phantom Zone.  I'll explain what I mean.

- When a question is closed, it gets one and only one shot at the reopen review queue, and an edit puts it there.
- Someone will post a question with a lot of problems and it will get closed.
- Someone will try to improve it, but their edit is inadequate.  However, it gets the question into the reopen review queue.
- Early reviewers see the inadequate edit and vote to leave it closed.
- Someone else then figures out how to turn it into a good question.
- The good question starts attracting votes to reopen.
- If the total leave-closed votes reaches three (e.g., a stray one after the edit before reaching enough votes to reopen), it completes the reopen review, leaving the question closed.

Now you have a good question in what I call the Phantom Zone; it's still some number of votes shy of reopening, but it will never get those votes because it becomes invisible.

- It isn't in the review queue and no action will put it back there.
- It might be temporarily featured in the Moderation Tools, and there's a chance that a 10K user will happen to see it, but that isn't reliable.
- There's a chance that some users with voting privileges, who haven't already voted on the question, will stumble across it.  But by then, the question is no longer fresh, so again, not reliable.

The appearance to users who might be following the question is that it's now a good one, there was some initial momentum to reopen it, and then for no apparent reason, it just stalled and remains closed.  They assume there's still some active process going on that should collect the remaining votes.  But the votes never come because the people who can reopen it are unaware of the need to vote on it.

My suggestion to address that is a slight change in how the reopen review queue works.  Currently, it just considers the running tally.  When leave-closed votes reaches three, the review is over.

It isn't unusual for several edits to be required to turn a bad question into a good one.  So starting the reopen vote tally after the first edit regardless of what happens afterward has a reasonable chance of arriving at a bad decision.

The proposed change is to add looking for a specific pattern that is characteristic of this situation:  Leave-closed votes, followed by an edit, followed by Reopen votes.  That pattern would restart the tally after the edit, so voting that reflects the current state of the question is what drives the reopen decision.

Comment: Why not post on the respective site's meta asking whether the question can be reopened or not?

Comment: @AnneDaunted, that's kind of the fallback solution.  But it has shortcomings.  1. It's not proactive, and a lot of it could simply be avoided.  2. If someone isn't actively following the question's status, the question can fall through the cracks entirely.  3. It may not be obvious for awhile that there's a reason to post on Meta.  4. If people don't think to check for this pattern, the voting (and lack of it) can be misleading.  It has the appearance that the status is already the will of the community.

Answer (score 4):

> Someone will try to improve it, but their edit is inadequate. However, it gets the question into the reopen review queue.

This is one of the problems, and whenever you see this happen you should inform the editor (e.g. via a comment). It's something people tend to forget (I made such a mistake a few weeks ago on Travel); some extra visibility would help but [such a proposal has been rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307590/295232).

> The first few reopen votes complete the reopen review, but the net voting leaves the question closed.

That isn't exactly how it works; a Reopen Votes review tasks is completed after three 'Leave Closed' actions or when the question is reopened. (There are some [edge cases](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3348/18673) which I still fail to grasp.)

Anyway, questions in the Phantom Zone are relatively rare. I suggest either to ping a few regulars in chat to help reopening the question, or as @AnneDaunted suggests, resort to Meta. Some sites, like Mathematics, have dedicated questions for this purpose: [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/228959) where you can post the request as an answer, while on The Workplace, the common procedure is to ask a new question tagged [[reopen-request]](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request).

Comment: Interesting reading, and the edge cases thread made my brain hurt.  Maybe network-wide, these Phantom Zone cases are rare, but I just dealt with two on Super User in the last couple of days, and the contributing factors, like multiple edits, are pretty common.  Thanks for clarifying the tally procedure.  Guess I misinterpreted the sequence in reading the question history.  The idea of restarting the tally after an edit if the edit was preceded by leave-closed votes (<3), and followed by reopen votes would still work.  (cont'd)

Comment: But the edge cases link illustrates that the action is way more complicated than the summary explanations.  They're probably not going to want to mess with the delicate balance.