# Allow edits by flaggers to push to the reopen queue under appropriate circumstances

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, flags, vote-to-reopen

#### Example

The following events happened to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/360625):

1. The question was asked being in a very unclear state (IMHO).
2. I flagged the question for closure (not having the close privilege) due to being unclear and left a comment asking for clarification.
3. The asker replied to my comment and edited the question. The edited question was still a chaotic mess, but it contained all information needed to solve the puzzle (what the question was about).
4. The question was closed.
5. I managed to make sense of the question with the new information and edited the question to make it understandable (IMHO).
6. The question was not pushed to the reopen queue because I flagged the question in Step 2.

#### Proposal

Assuming that my assessment of the qualities of the question are correct (if not, they will be for some other case), this is bad since the question will likely not be brought to the attention of those who could reopen it, even though it should be.

[The respective criterion for pushing to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074) is (boldface mine):

> a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is […] [e]dited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, **provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it**.

My guess is that the boldfaced restriction serves to exclude cases where somebody casts the last close vote and then performs an irrelevant edit or similar.
While this is reasonable, a narrower criterion would suffice to capture this and avoid false positives such as my example case.
It would suffice to refrain from pushing to the reopen queue if the editor has flagged (or voted to close) within, say, half an hour of the edit.

Also note that the boldfaced criterion does not matter that much for users with the close privilege, since they can just cast a reopen vote after performing the crucial edit.
Since I did not have that privilege, I could not do this.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is the most important one, really. Users with CV privileges *can*, if they so choose, (almost) always override the default system behavior that doesn't generate a reopen queue entry. Flaggers never can. So while the system's default behavior is usually reasonable, whenever it isn't, it's trivial for a CVer to correct it, but all but impossible for a flagger to do so. Therefore, the system fails safe for close votes, but *doesn't* for flags.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I really don't see the benefit of the restriction on flaggers at all

Comment: Log out and suggest the edit as an anonymous user.