# Why was the period for closed questions to enter the reopen queue extended from 5 days to 70 days?

Tags: support, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

It appears that on December 20, 2019, the team [increased the period of time for questions to enter the reopen queue from 5 days to 70 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/377214). There was no announcement made of this change at the time (as far as I could tell), and I only got to know about it after a post documenting the behavior was edited today by a former staff member.

Why was this change made? Was there some meta post or other notice that I missed? (I don't have an opinion on this change, I just want to know why it was made.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's all your fault.

Ha-ha, not really.

Well... Sorta; remember when you suggested that the new close notices should "[Making it clear that making an edit within five days will make the question be considered for reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339702#339702)? And [I replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339702#comment1134669_339702),

> ... on the "5 days to reopen" thing - that threshold is totally arbitrary, and will almost certainly change in the future; realistically we could make that unlimited without appreciably affecting anything right now. Tying it to a UI change made sense in 2013 when we had very little data on this stuff, but it's somewhere between confusing and actively misleading today... Getting rid of it frees us up to investigate more useful guidance.

Yeah, that.

*Eventually*, the time limit should just go away entirely. There are ongoing projects to redo the review queues *and* revamp closing, and that change would make sense as part of either.

But in the meanwhile, keeping an arbitrary 5-day limit didn't make any sense. Realistically, the most effective edits are made in *minutes* and keep the question from ever being closed... The next-most-effective edits happen in hours. By the time you're allowing *days*... There's not a particularly good reason to differentiate between 3 and 10, or... 5 and 70.

So it's 70 because to avoid flooding the queue I was bumping it up a little bit every week starting in early December, then I took a short break over the holidays, and then took an, uh, unintended *infinitely-long* break following the holidays. There's nothing special about 70, other than that it's far enough out that nobody should really have to worry about it.