# Help center page on reopening questions no longer correctly states the time frame in which edited questions are added to the reopen queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, help-center

In the [help center entry for reopening a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), the article states:

> Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening.

However, this is no longer correct, as this was [changed to 70 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353603/why-was-the-period-for-closed-questions-to-enter-the-reopen-queue-extended-from) in December 2019.

Also, in the new Reopen votes queue's onboarding dialog ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJia.png)), it asserts that posts whose bodies are edited within 70 days of closure are pushed into the reopen votes queue.

I'm pretty sure [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/622284) and the new dialog are correct here. Can the help center be updated accordingly?

Comment: That statement should probably be more accurate, so something like: "The first edit to the question's body text within the first 70 days of closure by a user who has not voted to close the question and who has not, and does not, flag or vote to reopen the question will automatically put the question into a review queue to be considered for reopening."

Comment: @Makyen I feel that that would overcomplicate what is supposed to be a help center page. (For what it's worth, in the [review FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), I simplified it by stating "posts that the system has determined may be eligible for reopening" and linking to another answer that elaborates it in detail - this also covers the case of "sufficiently popular" questions being added to the queue automatically immediately upon closure.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The situation is complex. Linking to somewhere covering it in more detail is reasonable, particularly if we can reduce the number of places where the details are stated, so we're not changing 50 places each time a detail changes. Overall, there's the choice of either being accurate or giving people information which is definitely wrong and *will* confuse some of them when the system doesn't do what's stated. The thing I'm against is giving people inaccurate information, without telling them it's simplified and not linking to a more detailed accurate description.

Comment: It looks like the wording of the help center page was updated in August 2021 to correspond with the changes detailed in the post [Changing the question reopening experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/335251), and the mention of a time limit was removed from that help center page at that time.