# How can I self-answer my closed question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, closed-questions, self-answer

I posted a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195494/enumerate-list-of-noise-algorithm-for-3d-terrain-heighmap-generation), however it was closed with a reason I don't understand.

I've found the answer myself and I would like to share the answer with the community, is there any way I can leave the answer?

By the way: It is said that question needs to be more focused, but I've already found a single valid answer myself. Noise functions are scientific questions of mathematics - and all mathematical questions always have a single valid comprehensive answer!

Comment: No, sorry. The definition and purpose of question closure is to preclude any answers being posted. You could ask a question here appealing the closure, and making a strong detailed case why your question does not need “more focus” (saying you found the answer yourself won’t convince people to re-open it).

Comment: It looks like "Needs more focus" was just the standard close reason that fit best - the core of your question is "could you please enumerate know noise algorithms for different types of landscape." and a [comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195494/enumerate-list-of-noise-algorithm-for-3d-terrain-heighmap-generation#comment355461_195494) clarifies "Questions soliciting open-ended lists are not well-suited to the StackExchange format. Try asking about one specific landscape at a time..." - which is true, open-ended lists to "enumerate" tend to not work great here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1606/discussion-between-dmytro-brazhnyk-and-bryan-krause).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit your question to make it more focused / less broad. That will put it into the Reopen Votes review queue (because the edit happened [within 70 days after closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/295232)) and other users will consider it for reopening.

> I've already found single valid answer my self

That's nice, but that doesn't mean there aren't also many more answers to your question. That is *precisely* what the close reason is trying to say.

**Don't** edit your answer into your question. That's not what questions are for; search engines don't know how to handle this properly, and users seeing the question in the [search results](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=noise+algorithms) notice that there are no answers to that question and skip it. Reviewers in the Reopen Votes review queue will see the original close reason has not been addressed with the edit and might leave it closed for that reason, preventing you from using the easiest route to get your question reopened.

Comment: @Glorfinderl I agree with you that if I found and answer It doesn't means that there is no other valid answers. But this question isn't that type of questions which have multiple valid answers. Perlin noise function is something like a wheel, it is used for 30 years by computer graphics industry. It is implemented in every engine and it is in every book. If I would ask which shape of wheel should I use for telega/car/bicycle, I hardly believe that here will be opinions about using rectangular wheels.