# Give 2k users a 'don't put this in the reopen queue' checkbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

I'm 3k, and have been reviewing reopen votes.

There are some items that show up the queue (some of the `this question was`**`edited`**`after being closed` ones), which have revisions obviously not intended to reopen the question.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2224761), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2246940), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2217191).

A grammar fix there, formatting here, type of fix - not a 2k user trying to get a question reopened.

We have to remember that each one of these 'fixer-upper' edits that hits the Reopen queue wastes 3-6 people's time, and increases the chance that the question may be reopened in error.

So, I propose that to fix this, we give 2k users a **<kbd>✓</kbd> `Submit this post for reopening` checkbox.**

The box would be selected by default, and placed in a relatively conspicuous place for the 2k user making an edit to check.

Comment: Do you think that anyone who got their question closed would want to edit it and NOT increase the chances of the question getting reopened? I bet this checkbox would never be used. For better or for worse, folks care a lot more about their questions getting answers than someone else's time.

Comment: I don't know that it's common enough to justify the space on the screen (but happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: The OP didn't choose to have is question closed. Why would he choose for it to stay closed ? Also, he doesn't get to choose that. The community does.

Comment: @AnnaLear Good point - one question: Do 2k edits bump the post into the review queue?

Comment: @AnnaLear The question isn't going to be exclusively edited by the OP.  They might not use it, but someone else editing it might.  (That said, I still agree it wouldn't get enough use to be worth implementing.)

Comment: @Undo Not the suggested edits review queue, but the reopen review queue, yes.

Comment: @Servy This post specifically talks about *post owners*.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd The OP does occasionally choose to have their question closed. Heck, [sometimes they even cast the first vote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579045/generate-content-type-header-from-extension), especially if they've found a convincing duplicate.

Comment: @AnnaLear The question's been edited since.

Comment: @Asad Right. Can't see it I'm not 3K on SO..

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd There's one close vote - apparently from the post owner.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157584/should-questions-be-added-to-the-reopen-queue-as-soon-as-theyre-edited-by-the-o#comment514253_157584) only OP's edits place the post in the review queue. If I'm reading the SQL query that powers the review queue right, that's still in effect and edits by other users don't place posts in the Reopen queue (although reopen votes from other users do).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the release [Review queue workflows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) final release, we have included functionality that addressed this. Users editing closed questions will now be shown a box that allows them to indicate if they're making a minor edit or a significant edit (should be considered for reopening in the Reopen votes queue).

[image: Post edit screen with significant edit option]

See the **Changes to the Reopen votes queues** section of that post for all of the details.

Answer (score 11):

While we now *do* add questions to the reopen queue [in response to 3rd-party edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), we ignore those where the editor has given some indication that he doesn't want the post reopened (voting to delete and flagging are pretty strong indicators here, so that's what we go with). An explicit checkbox clutters the UI with what *should* be a boring implementation detail, so we're not going to do that.

If you're making a lot of edits on posts that are closed - *nominated for deletion* - but which you explicitly *do not* want to see reopened... Then perhaps consider spending a bit less time rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic and instead putting that time and effort into other, more constructive activities.

Comment: If a 3K user edits, will that throw it into the review queue?  Or do you assume that person will cast a reopen vote if they think it should be reopened?

Comment: There's no rep restriction on this at present, @psubsee2003. Obviously though, if you *really* want a question to be re-opened, you should caste your vote.

Comment: Reconsideration request here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326978/add-a-checkbox-to-indicate-whether-a-third-party-edit-makes-the-question-reopena

Answer (score 10):

When this happens to me I don't vote to re-open, unless I believe that the question shouldn't have been closed in the first place. It really doesn't take up more than 30 seconds of my time so I don't mind.

As Anna commented, the OP would, I'm sure, like their question reopened if at all possible anyway, unless they've already got their answer. It's unlikely they would click the check-box.

What I've found this feature really useful for is not only helping people reopen their questions when it's deserved but catching people engaging in vandalism of their own posts. You can go to the post and rollback any changes made making this a fairly valuable tool.

Comment: Good point about catching vandalism.