# Be able to vote on question decisions

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

For example:

A question was closed with this:

> "closed as not a real question by Will May 14 at 17:55"

It could be a UP and DOWN marker in left side of this decision. So the users could vote if it was a good or bad decision. If it receives too many negative votes, it could be reversed.

Comment: We already do this using reviews, for the most part.

Comment: do you want something like currently exists (close votes) except for everyone as a suggestion for those who can cast close votes by those who can't?

Comment: Then if the question is reopened, can we have a thing where we vote on if it was a good call to reopen the question?

Comment: @WesleyMurch That's called close votes.  They're already a thing.

Comment: @Servy Wasn't done with my comment, sry. `</sarcasm>` There.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can already vote to reopen a post once it's closed if you have enough reputation (3000 points at least).

Comment: Is it also true that if you edit [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4020909/814064) it will automatically show up in the re-open queue?

Comment: @dcaswell I don't think it's automatic upon editing. I think someone has to cast a reopen vote for it to go to the queue.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Are you sure? Quote from [Reopen Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3133003): "This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?".

Comment: @BilltheLizard Editing the *body* of a closed or on-hold question throws it into the reopen queue unless you have cast a delete vote against the question. The question shows up in the re-open queue with the question and the revision difference between the current state of the question and the state when it was closed. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196080/226630)

Comment: @Linuxios No, I'm not sure. In fact, I think I'm wrong.  That question has no reopen votes, so I it looks like editing does now place some closed questions in the queue. (See Bad Wolf's comment above for the somewhat complicated rules someone came up with.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I like being right ;).

Comment: @Linuxios Well, they keep changing the damned rules on me.  :)

Comment: I believe it is the first time, and only the first time, its edited after its closed that throws it into the reopen queue

Comment: Is it 3k reputation as @Linuxios said?

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli Yes, you need 3000 reputation to cast either close or reopen votes.

Comment: I think you might soon be the first user network-wide to have 100k rep  on 2 sites... congrats in advance! :)

Comment: @yoda I didn't even realize that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Not needed. If there's a problem with a close decision, there's the "Reopen" option. If something is so controversial that it needs discussion and voting, bring it to Meta.

Comment: Bring it to Meta does not work because people here are hostile. A simple vote UP / DOWN in front of decision could help to bring problems here with more evidence that it was a bad or good decision.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli People here are largely not hostile unless they are first met with hostility.  If you come here and insult the community, make lots of demands, and aren't open to understanding why the action taken was correct, then you will be met with hostility.  If you come here to understand why the given actions were taken without judging them then you will generally be met with very positive and constructive feedback.

Comment: If you have a closed question with a good reasoning as to why it should be reopened, you'll find that posting on Meta might have your question reopened pretty fast @FelipeMicaroniLalli. It's when it really shouldn't be that they won't. But that's not hostile.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: Just as Servy says. There are also lots of safeguards like the reopen queue to prevent good content from being closed.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: Sure. Once you reach 3000 reputation, you'll also be able to cast reopen votes yourself.

Comment: I think it is a kind of hostile to say "Not needed." It can be a bad idea, but "not needed"? I needed it, otherwise I wouldn't post here. If it is really not needed, it could be more clear, at least. I understand why here is like this, it is similar Meta on Wikipedia. It is just opinions against opinions, not exact science.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: Sorry if that sounded hostile. I said "not needed" because it duplicates existing features of the site.

Comment: @Felipe if you consider that hostile then I suggest investing in thicker skin. That wasn't hostile at all. Maybe a bit terse, but would "The feature you're requesting is not necessary" really be any less hostile than "Not needed"? I don't think so, because neither of those statements should be interpreted as hostile by any reasonable human.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me sounds like I was too stupid and I didn't see that it was so clear that feature wasn't necessary. When I was using a question on StackOverflow I just thought: "it would be nice if I could see what the community think about this decision", because I would like to know if that "close" was well done or not. But OK, thank you all for answers. :)

Comment: Should I remove this question? I think a question with negative votes ins't useful for the community. It was my mistake.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli You couldn't, even if you wanted to, because the question has upvoted answers.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: On meta, negative votes just indicate disagreement.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: The fact that you came to meta with a suggestion and not a rant is a huge vote in your favor :).