# Flag to put a closed question in the Reopen queue (just like we have for the Close queue)

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

A few days ago, I found an interesting question on Music.SE that was closed. I wanted it to be reopened, but I couldn't find any typo or small problem that I can fix with an edit to put it into the Reopen queue. I decided to use a custom flag saying "This question should be reopened."

However, I can see how these flags can cause problems. Most importantly, these flags make moderators reopen questions, which is supposed to be a *community process*. Secondly, they make it slow to reopen the questions.

The lack of direct appearance in the reopen queue with custom flags like this might also make users with editing but not vote-to-reopen privileges submit a crappy edit to get the post into the reopen queue. Therefore, I think there should be an option to flag a closed question for reopening, directly putting it in the Reopen queue, just like there is a flag to close questions that puts the question directly in the Close queue.

Comment: Was about to answer here, but this got closed as a dupe, so [answered the target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386899/377214).